Issues with optim function: Parameters Stuck Around Initial Values
I am experiencing issues with the optim function in R, where it seems to get stuck near the initial parameter values and does not explore the parameter space effectively. Below is a simplified version of my code:
empirical_data <- rnorm(10000, mean = 400, sd = 580)
ks_mean_sd_cost_function <- function(params) {
   mean_param <- params[1] 
   sd_param <- params[2]
   simulated_data <- rnorm(100, mean = mean_param, sd = sd_param)
   ks_stat <- ks.test(empirical_data, simulated_data)$statistic
   return(as.numeric(ks_stat))
}

starting_params <- c(mean(empirical_data), 
sd(empirical_data))

result <- optim(
par = starting_params,
fn = ks_mean_sd_cost_function,
method = "L-BFGS-B",
lower = c(starting_params[1], starting_params[2]),
upper = c(starting_params[1]*10, starting_params[2]*10))

print(result)

I know by design that I can only have a higher mean. We are talking about plant ranges, and we can only under estimate it.
Here is a quick look at what it does on every iteration :
Current parameters: mean = 399.9686 , sd = 580.1356
Current parameters: mean = 399.9696 , sd = 580.1356
Current parameters: mean = 399.9686 , sd = 580.1356
Current parameters: mean = 399.9686 , sd = 580.1366

Here are the specific issues I'm encountering:

The optimization parameters oscillate around the starting values without significant exploration.
Despite setting relatively large bounds, the parameter values do not change much. It should try to find the best parameters for rlnorm

Things I've Tried

Ensured the bounds are sufficiently large.
Verified that the cost function returns a meaningful and variable value.

Despite these efforts, the optimization process still fails to explore the parameter space effectively, and circles back to the starting parameters.

The usual cause of an optimiser getting stuck is that there are multiple local maxima and it climbs to the nearest peak from where it was started. If that isn't good enough then I suggest you try either simplex methods or slightly easier to use but slower simulated annealing which can work well on difficult global optimisation problems when everything else has failed.

optim should not be used with functions whose output depends on random numbers.

There has been a brief discussion on noisy objective functions recently on R-help: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2023-August/477884.html
